# Setting timeout for query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have data warehouse setting where we use oracle 12c and informatica for ETL. We call some hourly procedures in informatica workflow. Sometimes these procedures take more than one hour for various reasons. Is it possible to set timeout event to generate mail alert at database level or informatica level which will terminate current execution and generate mail alert for the same.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Well... no. This and a bunch of other features are not part of Informatica. Here an external Orchestration tool is very much helpful. One that takes care of file watching and triggering workflows upon file arrival, reports that a workflow runs too long or too short, one that will notify in case a file you expect to get has not been received and so on.